# how do I view tables that I have created using azure query editor?

Tags: sql, azure

I created a sql database using azure. And also I created some tables in that database. Now I want to view those tables. I tried "show tables" command using query editor. But It doesn't work.what is the correct way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you using SSMS or the Azure portal? You click on the Database, then expand Tables and they should show.

Comment: You might need to right click in SSMS and refresh to show the latest table schema.

Comment: i am using azure portal. actually i am new to azure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

SELECT name FROM sys.tables